# In Sitecore, can you have standard values set on a template that uses a queryable treelist?

Tags: templates, xpath, sitecore

I have a sitecore template that uses a queryable treelist. I want to set the src of this template to have a dynamic value based on where it lives in the tree.

I'm doing something like this:

```
 DataSource=query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/*[@@templatename='Settings']
```

This works fine for grabbing the source, but I'd love to have standard values set for the selected items. Is it possible? Or will that be a problem, since you can't determine the context of the item/template until it is already instantiated in the tree? Since the lists might end up with different items in them, I wasn't sure if standard value could be set by name rather than guid.

Answer (score 0):

First enable viewing Raw Values in the View ribbon.

Then go to the `__Standard Values` item of the template and set the field value to a list of GUID's separated by a pipe. Like: `{guid}|{guid}`

This should result in those items being selected by default.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem completely, as the selected items are "based on where it lives in the tree". but it probably the closest to an answer...